# Сканирование директории

Tags: файлы, ruby

Хочу написать функцию для поиска файлов, содержащих заданную строку. Функция должна просканировать дерево директориев, и найти первый файл, содержащий строку, имя которого соответствует маске.

Почему это не работает?

```
enter @files = Dir.glob("*.txt") 
for file in @files 
    puts file 
end
here
```

Я пытаюсь указать директиву и маску и циклом занести в массив все txt. Потом мне нужно будет сравнить все txt с строкой, которую я введу (уже при запуске программы). В итоге я должен показать все txt, в которых содержится та строка.

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу про вопрос. Несомненно, желание написать функцию само по себе похвально :)

Comment: В том что написал я только...а дальше не знаю. 
basedir = "D:\edr"
contains = Dir.new(basedir).entries
puts contains

Comment: Это учебное задание? И опять на Ruby?

Comment: да. да это опять Ruby.

Comment: Тогда отредактируйте вопрос, добавив свое решение, и скажите, что не получилось.

Comment: @Николай Биленко - Не надо отвечать на свой вопрос, для уточнений есть комментарии и правка вопроса.

Comment: Напишите функцию
для поиска файлов, содержащих заданную строку.
Прототип функции: char* FindFileByText (char*
szStartDir, char* szFileMask, char* szTextPattern);
Ваша функция должна
просканировать дерево директориев, начиная со стартового szStartDir, и найти первый
файл, содержащий строку szTextPattern, имя которого соответствует маске szFileMask.

Answer (score 3):

Если нужен просто метод, который находит один или более файлов и возвращает список в виде масива, то можно воспользоваться прекрасным методом описанным в книге Хэла Фултона "Программирование на языке RUBY" стр. 305

Собственно код:

```
def findfiles(dir, name)
  list = []
  Find.find(dir) do |path|
    Find.prune if [".", ".."].include? path
    case name
      when String
        list << path if File.basename(path) == name
      when Regexp
        list << path if File.basename(path) =~ name
      else
        raise ArgumentError
    end
  end
  list
end
```

Вызов может быть, например, таким:

```
findfiles "C:/" /txt/
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте дерево из имен файлов и ищите в нем.